# how i can check is my database alive?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

in my zf application i have base model class Application_Model, which connects to db and stores connection in registry.
part of code:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory($registry['config']->$databaseAlias->db->adapter, $registry['config']->$databaseAlias->db->config->toArray());
        $db -> query('SET NAMES ' . $registry['config']->$databaseAlias->db->config->setnames);
        $db -> setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
        Zend_Registry::set('db', array($databaseAlias=>$db));
```

if mysql server is shut down,  `$db -> query('SET NAMES ' . $registry['config']->$databaseAlias->db->config->setnames);` throws exception. that's not what i want.
actualy i want to check somehow, if my database dead - do some actions;
is there any way to do so?

Comment: You can't know if it's down if you don't try to connect to it. Why not put a `try..catch` block around the connection code and handle the server being down when it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could throw a try/catch around the db call, and if it gets into the catch, do the actions you want

```
try
{
    $db = Zend_Db::factory(
        $registry['config']->$databaseAlias->db->adapter,
        $registry['config']->$databaseAlias->db->config->toArray()
    );
    $db -> query('SET NAMES ' . $registry['config']->$databaseAlias->db->config->setnames);
    $db -> setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
    Zend_Registry::set('db', array($databaseAlias=>$db));
} catch( \Exception $e ) {
    // Database query failed, do logic here
}
```

Comment: oh, so obvious :) thx
that tells me "dont take new task at the end of working day" ))

Answer (score 1):

Trial and error with a try/catch Block!
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php